# Anaconda installation not finding packages

Tags: python, anaconda, seaborn, conda

This one is best shown through what I'm trying to do and what is going on.

In my python file, I want to import seaborn.

It's available to install via conda.

```
(me_dev)[me@ip-***]$ conda install seaborn
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: ............................
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/me/miniconda/envs/me_dev:
#
seaborn                   0.7.0                    py27_0

(me_dev)[me@ip-***** ****]$ which python
~/miniconda/bin/python

(me_dev)[me@ip-****]$ which ipython
~/miniconda/bin/ipython
```

Now if I start iPython and import seaborn:

```
In [1]: import seaborn
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-085c0287ecb5> in <module>()
----> 1 import seaborn

ImportError: No module named seaborn
```

Also, pip is not working either. It's not reading packages from pip.

```
(me_dev)[me@ip-*****]$ pip install jellyfish
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): jellyfish in /home/me/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Yet:

```
from jellyfish import jaro_winkler ImportError: No module named jellyfish
```

Edit:
sys.path looks like so in iPython

```
['',
 '/home/me/miniconda/bin',
 '/home/me/miniconda/lib/python27.zip',
 '/home/me/miniconda/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/me/miniconda/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/me/miniconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/me/miniconda/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/me/miniconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/me/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-19.6.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/me/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/me/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography-1.0.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/home/me/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/me/.ipython']
```

Here's my .bashsrc

```
(me_dev)[me@ip-**** ~]$ cat .bashrc
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

# added by Miniconda 3.16.0 installer
export PATH="/home/me/miniconda/bin:$PATH"

# User specific aliases and functions
source activate me_dev

# added by Miniconda2 3.19.0 installer
export PATH="/home/me/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Could you let us see your `sys.path` ?

Comment: Just added to the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `which python` (and `which ipython`) should be pointing at `~/miniconda/envs/me_dev/bin/`, not at `~/miniconda/bin/` directory. When you start an python session with those binaries, they can't see your seaborn library, which is probably only installed in the environment site packages.

<s>I'm not sure exactly how you ended up in this state, but I would recommend trying to make a new environment and see if you end up pointed at the correct binaries.</s>

The organization your `.bashrc` is the problem. You're activating your virtual environment, but then giving the main miniconda `bin` directory precedence in your `$PATH`, which has the effect of partially inactivating the virtual environment.

Comment: You can work without virtual environment (tested here), as long as you have permissions to install packages in the "global" installation directory. That said, you're right, it's better to work in virtual environments, and that could solve the problem.

Comment: I am working in a virtual/conda environment, and that's why you see me_dev in front of everything.

Comment: mwaskom -- Trying that now

Comment: @mwaskom check my edit. So I cloned me_dev and then deleted the original then went back and remade the original. If I source activate, it works fine, but it seems like it isn't working and pointing to the right option when I re-login to the server. Is it something in the bash?

Comment: I'm fairly certain the last line in your `.bashrc` is the problem.

Comment: Yep that is right! Basically I accidentally uninstalled miniconda, and when I re-installed it added the last line.